# Customizing the ListItem color android_simple_listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In order to customize the color of `android simple list item 1` i have made a styles.xml which  looks like

```
<resources>
    <style name="BlackText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and applied it to my activity in the manifest file like

```
 android:theme="@style/BlackText"
```

this sort of resolved my problem the color of default list item is changed to black but the text color of my dialog on that activity is also changed to black which i dont want to. Oe alternative is to make my my own `adapter` and override the `bindView` method which i dont want to make are there any other alternatives...?

EDIT

i made my own layout like

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/somerandomid"

    android:padding="5sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and used it like

```
 adapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(SomeActivity.this,R.layout.myownlayout, cursor, columns, views);
```

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you just create your own list item layout and apply the style to that? The android simple_list_item_1 layout is literally just a LinearLayout with a single TextView in it - trivial to replicate.

Comment: i copied pasted the `simple_list_item_1 layout` code to my own lay out it sort of worked but the background color and text color was not applying ...

Comment: Why aren't you using an `ArrayAdapter` and instead using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: @hichris123 because im fetching the results from database on which i have to perform further actions based on user selection

Answer (score 1):

So what you could do instead of binding the ListView to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, you could create your own layout with one `TextView`. Let's say the layout would be called `listviewlayout.xml`. It would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

You may need to move the `TextView` around to get it in the right position. Then, remove this part from your manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/BlackText"
```

And then set the ListView adapter like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listviewlayout, listItems));
```

Comment: i tried that plz see the edits i made to the question, but the white background and black text color is not showing

Comment: the text is not appearing but the listitem is there it responds to long click and on the dialog box name of item appears correctly but not on the list the back ground is white

Answer (score 0):

apparently i had to copy the id same as specified in the default layout, so i changed

```
android:id="@+id/somerandomid"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/text1"
```

and things went well for me